# how can I create a table and insert this label and textfield when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I am new in programming and
I have created a form.
I want to insert this elements in the table when I click the add button

I already know how to add label and textfield and I want to know how to add row and insert new label and textfield in the table

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
var x = 1;

function add(type) {
    var newlabel = document.createElement("Label");
    newlabel.for = "Name";
    newlabel.innerHTML = "NAME: ";

    var element = document.createElement("input");
    element.setAttribute("type", type);
    element.setAttribute("name", type);
    element.setAttribute("value", "Name"+x);
    element.setAttribute("id", "Name"+x);
    element.setAttribute("style","width: 64");

    var newlabel1 = document.createElement("Label");
    newlabel1.for = "AGE";
    newlabel1.innerHTML = "AGE: ";  

    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.setAttribute("type", type);
    element1.setAttribute("name", type);
    element1.setAttribute("value", "AGE"+x);
    element1.setAttribute("id", "AGE"+x);
    element1.setAttribute("style","width: 64");

    var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
    foo.appendChild(newlabel);
    foo.appendChild(element);
    foo.appendChild(newlabel1);
    foo.appendChild(element1);

    x++;
}
</script>

<form id="fooBar" form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <table id = "mytable" table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">name: </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <label for="name"></label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
            </th>
            <th scope="col">age:</th>
            <th scope="col">
                <label for="name2"></label>
                <input type="text" name="name2" id="name2">
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <INPUT type="button" value="Add" onClick="add('text')" style="width:100px;"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Please add a little HTML for context. Also, I won't answer using jQuery but as a new developer you should look into it. It gets you rolling on JavaScript and is a gentle way to start learning JavaScript.

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame—jQuery is useless for someone learning javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code:

```
> <SCRIPT language="javascript">
```

The language attribute for script elements is deprecated, type is required, use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

...

> newlabel.setAttribute("for", "Name");

The value of the [for](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-for) attribute must match the ID of a form control, otherwise it will not be associated with the control. Also, it is easier and more robust to set element properties rather that use setAttribute:

```
 newlabel.htmlFor = "Name";
```

Note that the HTML *for* attribute is referenced as the [*htmlFor*](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#dom-label-htmlfor) property because *for* is a reserved word in javascript (actually ECMAScript).

```
> newlabel.innerHTML = "NAME:    ";
```

Rather than using the innerHTML property, you should probably be appending a text node:

```
 newlabel.appendChild(document.createTextNode("NAME:    "));
```

Your HTML should look like:

```
<form id="fooBar">
  <input type="button" value="Add fields" onclick="add();">
</form>
```

Note that if you are using a [BUTTON](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-BUTTON) element, that what might be happening is that the form is being submitted (because button elements are, by default, submit buttons) so the fields are being added but because the form submits, you don't see it. Make sure the button is type="button".

Comment: thank you i revise my code already and how can i add row to a table and insert the fields?

Comment: You are trying to add the elements to another element with an ID of "foobar", but there is no such element in the page. Use either `document.form1` in the function or add an ID of "foobar" to the form.

Answer (score 0):

ive made it need feedback/comments :)

```
 <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
var x =1;

function add(type,tabID) {

var tbody = document.getElementById(tabID).getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
var row = document.createElement("tr")
var data1 = document.createElement("td")    
var data2 = document.createElement("td") 
var data3 = document.createElement("td") 
var data4 = document.createElement("td") 


var newlabel = document.createElement("Label");
newlabel.for = "Name";
newlabel.innerHTML = "NAME: ";

var element = document.createElement("input");
element.setAttribute("type", type);
element.setAttribute("name", type);
element.setAttribute("value", "Name"+x);
element.setAttribute("id", "Name"+x);


var newlabel1 = document.createElement("Label");
newlabel1.for = "AGE";
newlabel1.innerHTML = "AGE: ";  


var element1 = document.createElement("input");
element1.setAttribute("type", type);
element1.setAttribute("name", type);
element1.setAttribute("value", "AGE"+x);
element1.setAttribute("id", "AGE"+x);


var foo = document.tbody;

data1.appendChild(newlabel)
data2.appendChild(element)
data3.appendChild(newlabel1)
data4.appendChild(element1)

row.appendChild(data1)
row.appendChild(data2)
row.appendChild(data3)
row.appendChild(data4)
tbody.appendChild(row);


x++;

}

</script>

<form  id="fooBar" form name="form1" method="post" action="">
 <table id = "mytable" table border="1">
 <tr>
<th scope="col">name: </th>
<th scope="col">
  <label for="name"></label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  </th>
  <th scope="col">age:</th>
  <th scope="col">
  <label for="name2"></label>
  <input type="text" name="name2" id="name2">
</th>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <INPUT type="button" value="Add" onClick="add('text','mytable')" style="width:100px;"/>
 </form>
```